# How to Run Code After Baking With 'INVOKE_DEFAULT' Has Finished?

Tags: python, scripting, texture-baking, baking

```
bpy.ops.object.bake('INVOKE_DEFAULT', type='DIFFUSE')
save_image()
```

Does not work because the bake uses `'INVOKE_DEFAULT'` and thus `save_image` will be executed directly.

**How to run `save_image` after the baking has finished?**

Comment: Don't invoke default?  If you are after user input could write an operator or macro to invoke and feed arguments into bake op.

Comment: But this freezes the UI and no progress bar is shown

Comment: @RobertGützkow sounds good, but I can't find a handler for "bake_post" or something similar

Comment: @RobertGützkow unfortunately, neither `render_post` nor `render_complete` is triggered

Comment: The options to save the baked image externally doesn't appear to work either. I'll put it on my to do list.

Answer (score 6):

Although the question is old, can help more developers. 
You can create a modal operator and check the state of the 'is_dirty' property of the image.

```
import bpy

class ModalTimerOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "wm.modal_timer_operator"
    bl_label = "Modal Timer Operator"
    _timer = None
    _img = None

    def modal(self, context, event):
        if event.type in {'RIGHTMOUSE', 'ESC'}:
            self.cancel(context)
            return {'CANCELLED'}

        if event.type == 'TIMER':
            if self._img.is_dirty: # <--- Wait until the image is marked as dirty
                self.finish(context)
                return {'FINISHED'}

        return {'PASS_THROUGH'}

    def execute(self, context: bpy.context):
        if context.scene.render.engine != 'CYCLES':
            context.scene.render.engine = 'CYCLES'
        
        if not context.active_object.select_get() or not context.active_object.type == 'MESH':
            self.report({'WARNING'}, "No valid selected objects")
            return {'FINISHED'}

        obj = context.active_object
        mats = obj.data.materials
        mats_len = len(mats)

        if mats_len == 0 or not mats[0]:
            mat_new = bpy.data.materials.new('BakeMaterial')
            if mats_len == 0:
                mats.append(mat_new)
            else:
                mats[0] = mat_new
            pass

        mat = mats[0]
        mat.use_nodes = True
        nodes = mat.node_tree.nodes
        tex_node = nodes.new('ShaderNodeTexImage')
        tex_node.name = 'BakeNode'
        tex_node.select = True
        nodes.active = tex_node
        self._img = bpy.data.images.new('BakeResult', 1024, 1024)
        tex_node.image = self._img

        self.report({'INFO'}, "Execute")
        result = bpy.ops.object.bake('INVOKE_DEFAULT', type='DIFFUSE')
        if result != {'RUNNING_MODAL'}: # <--- Important to check the result
            self.report({'WARNING'}, "Failed to start baking")
            return {'FINISHED'}

        wm = context.window_manager
        self._timer = wm.event_timer_add(0.5, window=context.window)
        wm.modal_handler_add(self)
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def cancel(self, context):
        self.report({'INFO'}, "Baking map cancelled")

    def finish(self, context):
        wm = context.window_manager
        wm.event_timer_remove(self._timer)
        self.report({'INFO'}, "Baking map completed")
        #save_image() # <--- Call the function after baking

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ModalTimerOperator)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ModalTimerOperator)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
    bpy.ops.wm.modal_timer_operator()
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. Great script.
As a side note, once the image data is baked, is_dity returns true.
If you want to bake that image over again, you need to pack the image once.
In

```
self._img.pack()
```

, the value of is_dirty returns false.
Now you can create a modus operandi that bakes images on top of each other.

When overlapping bakes, scene settings should also be reviewed.

```
bpy.context.scene.render.bake.use_clear = False
```