# Run operator not freezing Blender UI

Tags: python, scripting, baking, operator, system

**Problem:**

I need an example of an operator that is used for baking image texture using Blender's `bpy.ops.bake`. I need to have it running modal to prevent Blender's UI from freezing, a progress bar to display the baking progress, and an option to cancel the execution if `ESC` pressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the desired answer in [Modal Baking Operator](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/170386/how-to-run-code-after-baking-with-invoke-default-has-finished/253550#253550) by @Carnerio.
Editing my code to fit the needs.

```
import bpy

class ModalTimerOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "wm.modal_timer_operator"
    bl_label = "Modal Timer Operator"
    _timer = None
    _img = None

    def modal(self, context, event):
        if event.type == 'ESC':
            self.cancel(context)
            return {'CANCELLED'}

        if event.type == 'TIMER':
            if self._img.is_dirty: # <--- Wait until the image is marked as dirty
                self.finish(context)
                return {'FINISHED'}

        return {'PASS_THROUGH'}

    def execute(self, context):
        if context.scene.render.engine != 'CYCLES':
            context.scene.render.engine = 'CYCLES'
    
        self._img = bpy.data.images[0]
        self.report({'INFO'}, "Execute")
    
        result = bpy.ops.object.bake('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
        if result != {'RUNNING_MODAL'}:
            self.report({'WARNING'}, "Failed to start baking")
            return {'FINISHED'}

        wm = context.window_manager
        self._timer = wm.event_timer_add(0.5, window=context.window)
        wm.modal_handler_add(self)
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def cancel(self, context):
        self.report({'INFO'}, "Baking map cancelled")

    def finish(self, context):
        wm = context.window_manager
        wm.event_timer_remove(self._timer)
        self.report({'INFO'}, "Baking map completed")

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ModalTimerOperator)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ModalTimerOperator)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
    #bpy.ops.wm.modal_timer_operator()
```